# Displaying decimal values in Qt using qreal Data Type

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to get decimal values using qreal in Qt??

just like this:

```
qreal decimal;
average = 3/2;
```

the output should definitely 1.5 but instead i am getting 1 as  result.

can anyone help me??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@andro, you could do (x*1.0)/y or (qreal)x/y

Comment: I personally find it clearer to write `qreal(x)/y`, as that makes it clearer that the cast happens _before_ the division, and it's therefore a FP division.

Answer (score 5):

Because everybody is saying how to solve the problem and not what is the problem, here is my answer:

Operations on integers returns integers. To get a real number you should cast one of the operands to a real type.

Answer (score 1):

```
qreal average;
average = 3.0/2;
```

Comment: @Andro: it's not, it's a constant ;-) But seriously, cast to double first: `x = double(a) / double(b);`